# maven и создание приложения Spring

Tags: java, spring

Подскажите, вот в мавене когда проект спринг делаю. Что нужно конкретно для создания простого легкого приложения, где используется только бины и DI почему все создавая проект добавляют в мавен много всего . я пробовал создавать проекты просто из спринг кор, и вроде все равботало все что нужно было(я имею ввиду создавались бины и DI). Дак почему многие добавляют в мавен строки  типа контекст, бин и еще какието , почему работает без них и что с ними вообще нужно делать для чего они. Может чета не то пишу, я только начинающий , учу самостаятельно по книге.

и если можно в кратце что такое и с чем едят: Spring Context, Spring Beans.
Начинаю путаться. Вот щас создаю опять проект мавен и думаю что действительно нужно подгружать из этого.

Comment: В [документации Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#overview-modules) более-менее подробно описано за что отвечает каждый модуль из вами перечисленных.

Answer (score 2):

Все зависит от задач, которые перед вами стоят.

Если вы хотите использовать `spring` как `DI` контейнер, то достаточно и одной зависимости `spring-context`. Не стоит забывать, что этот фреймворк достаточно большой. В ней есть куча проектов:

- spring boot
- spring mvc
- spring batch
- spring security
- spring integration
- и пр ([тыщи их](https://spring.io/projects))

Так же у `spring` есть компоненты, которые могут использоваться в перечисленных выше проектах. Самые базовые - это [spring DI](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context) и [spring AOP](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop), помимо них есть еще для работы с [транзакциями](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx), c [SPEL](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-expression) и пр.